# Python Plotly - interactively update figure properties

Tags: python, plotly, interactive

I am trying to learn working with Plotly and I have a straightforward question, which I couldn't find answered anywhere. I apologise if it's common knowledge...

I would like to learn how to interactively *update a figure*, without having to recreate it, but I don't find tutorial about that.

For instance, I can create a figure (let's say in a notebook) with

```py
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6])
```

And then I want to interactively modify the figure to set `y=[10, 20, 30]`.
I'd expect to run something similar to

```py
fig.update_traces(y=[10, 20, 30])
```

I found several examples in which the figure is *recomputed* but I wonder if it's possible to manipulate the original widget directly.

Hope you can point me in the right direction.
Thank you!

Comment: This might help you https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing